# iOS app compatible with 7 AND 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I've developed an app and i'm testing it in a iOS 8.1 device. Now a friend hand me a non-upgraded iPhone 5, with iOS 7.1.2, but when I tried to test the app iTunes said that is not compatible with my device.

I have the following values in XCode:

```
PROJECT > X > Info > iOS Deployment Target = “8.1"
PROJECT > X > Build Settings > Architectures > Base SDK = "Latest iOS"
PROJECT > X > Build Settings > Deployment > iOS Deployment Target = “iOS 8.1"
TARGETS > X > General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target = “iOS 8.1"
TARGETS > X > Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target > iOS Deployment Target = “iOS 8.1"
```

I think that I need to stablish what is the minimum OS version anywhere. At least that's what I do on Android (I'm way more skilled in Android that in iOS...) Can you please help me?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set "Deployment Target" lower.

Set it to 7.0, and you should be good to go, provided you haven't used any iOS 8-only stuff in your app.

Devices all the way back to iPhone 4 can have iOS 7 on them. If you need the 3GS, then I think you're looking at iOS 6 as your deployment target. Here's a list of which devices support which versions of iOS, plus other info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices

It's ok to leave the "Base SDK" at 8.1, or better yet, "Latest iOS".

Comment: Thank you both Almo and @Peter Segerblom, it worked perfectly. Hopefully I don't need to make this compatible with iOS 6 :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the deployment target to 7 and Base SDK should be set to "Latest IOS". This can be done under General respectively Build Settings of your target. If you are using any iOS 8 specific library you need to change them to Optional instead of required under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. Your app may still not work if it relies on iOS 8 specific thing.